# How to achieve this flutter scroll animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

Refer to this video I posted on facebook flutter group:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/409645446115733/permalink/1363664534047148/

*I managed to scale the width using Transform, but having challenge on overlap before pushing top item effect.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something with this, [stacked_card_carousel](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_card_carousel):

```
StackedCardCarousel(
    items: cards,
    type: //change type between cardsStack or fadeOutStack
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim. BTW, does it have function like unstack or scroll to top?

Comment: I think you can still use PageController to scroll to index 0 (scroll to top)

Comment: Thank again @Jim. PageController animate to 0 did the trick. Appreciate your help